# The code for switching views randomly is not functioning

Tags: ios, random, view, switch-statement

I have this code, at the moment it is not functioning correctly. When I click on the button to switch views, nothing happens. I am programming in Xcode 5. If you can help it is appreciated. The code is listed below.

-(IBAction)RandomButton:(id)sender {

```
int randomviews = rand() % 2;
switch (randomviews) {
    case 0:

    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                    @"Main.storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        Home *Next = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SummerWinter"];
        [self presentViewController:Next animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

        break;
    case 1:

    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                    @"Main.storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        Home *Next = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HiBye"];
        [self presentViewController:Next animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `rand()`, it is not random, use `arc4random()` and `arc4random_uniform()`.

rand() requires a seed and that is problematic, without an explicit seeding it starts with a seed of 1. With the same seed the sequence is repeatable.

arc4random() does not need a seed, it is seeded periodically by the system and is a cryptographically secure psudo-random number generator (PRNG).

In the OP case use:

```
int randomviews = arc4random_uniform(2);
```

Comment: The app still crashes after I changed the code. Do you have any other ideas of what it might be?

Comment: If the app is crashing add the crash log and backtrace to the question.